# Multisite: Other link color (css)

Tags: 7, theming, multi-sites

When using the same theme on multisites, what would be the easiest sollution to give each domain another link color?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try Domain CSS module if you are already using Domain Access module. ( https://drupal.org/project/domain_css )

This will give you ability to add additional css per domain so you can keep everything clean and organized.

Another alternative is to write a custom module and get $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; which you can run into switch statment to load css.

Similar question: [Load domain-specific CSS file on a multisite](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17009/load-domain-specific-css-file-on-a-multisite)

Comment: Too bad the module isn't available in Drupal 8